# Why I can't add newly created principal entity when use DbSet.Add()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two classes and they are in one to one relationship

```
public class Car
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

and let's say I have added one record (with id = 1) to the Company table, so now I want to add a new Car record as

```
Car c = new Car { Name = "car1" };
c.CompanyId = 1;
context.Cars.Add(c);
context.SaveChanges();
```

above approach works, I'm OK with that, but if I try the following approach, then it doesn't work and throw an exception(cannot add explicit value to identify column:

```
Car c = new Car { Name = "car1" };
Company com = new Company { Id = 1 };
c.Company = com;
context.Cars.Add(c);
context.SaveChanges();
```

so why DbSet.Add() thinks I'm adding a new Company record? can't it be smart enough to tell that there is already a company record whose id is 1 in the Company table?

Comment: You first option look perfectly fine to me. Any reason for going to 2nd option while first one is more simple and less code? This is default behavior of entity framework and better not to tweak with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DbContext` instance will add the relationships on the entity as added (new) items in the database which will be added when the changes are persisted (`SaveChanges`). You can manually change the state back to [`Unchanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitystate?view=efcore-2.1) for any entity that does not have changes.

```
Car c = new Car { Name = "car1" };
Company com = new Company { Id = 1 };
c.Company = com;
context.Cars.Add(c);

// mark the company as unchanged
context.Entry(com).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

context.SaveChanges();
```

Alternatively you can query the DbContext for an instance of `Company` and use that but this is 1 extra roundtrip to the database. The upside of this approach is the code might be easier to read/maintain.

Comment: could you also have a look at this post? thanks    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57503120/sequence-of-updates-after-calling-context-savechanges

Answer (score 0):

It's because by default the Entity framework tries to add two objects to the database with a relationship between them when you are creating a relationship between two **`new`** objects. You can prevent adding child objects with the:

```
context.Entry(com).State = EntityState.Detached
```

or you can just  try

```
Car c = new Car { 
    Name = "car1",
    Company = context.Companies.First(x => x.Id == 1)
};

context.Cars.Add(c);
context.SaveChanges();
```